# Where does the different behaviour of npm-executables in CMD and in Git Bash come from?

Tags: cmd, git-bash, browser-sync

I am using [`browser-sync`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-sync) and would like to know why there is a different behaviour when I am running

`browser-sync start --serve --files "*"`

either in the CMD

[image]

or the Git-Bash

[image]

Is that something about the different environments, which are at the disposal for the commands? Both commands were ran in the same directory so both should have had access to the `index.html`. But only the command in the CMD seems to find the file and can serve it.

Comment: The Windows command processor `cmd.exe` passes an argument like `"*"` as is to `browser-sync`. The script must itself support arguments with a wildcard pattern which is not the case according to the output. `bash` interprets `"*"` as wildcard pattern and replaces that argument string by a list of file names each enclosed in `"` before starting `browser-sync`. So with current directory containing `FileA.txt` and `File B.txt`, `bash` starts `browser-sync` with the arguments `start --serve --files "FileA.txt" "File B.txt"` while `cmd.exe` starts it with `start --serve --files "*"`.

Comment: A Windows command processor replacement for the `bash` command line would be `%ComSpec% /E:ON /Q /V:ON /C "set "FileNames=" & (for %I in (*) do if defined FileNames (set "FileNames=!FileNames! "%I"") else set "FileNames="%I"") & if defined FileNames browser-sync start --serve --files !FileNames!`. It would be much better if author of `browser-sync` extends the script to support itself arguments with wildcard patterns. Then it could be used with `browser-sync start --serve --files *` in `cmd` and with `browser-sync start --serve --files '*'` with shell interpreters like `bash`, `dash`, ...